# Changing order of affiliation

Tags: revtex, affiliation

I have problem to change order of affiliation in my paper 
I have three authors, but in a list of affiliation, I want it to start with affiliation of third authors.

this is a sample the input. I have to do something that affiliation of Author C are shown in top of list which start with number 1. in my input, affiliation of first author is shown with number 1

I tried to use `authblk` package, but one error stopped compiling which was `\c@affil` already defined

Thank you so much for your help in advance

```
\documentclass[article,osajnl,showpacs,superscriptaddress,twocolumn,10.5pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,gensymb,gensymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\let\bibhang\relax
\let\citename\relax
\let\textcite\relax
\let\bibfont\relax
\let\Citeauthor\relax
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\def\bibsection{\section*{References}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}



\begin{document}
\title{XXXXXX}

\author{A}
\affiliation{affiliation1}
\author{B}
\affiliation{affiliation2}
\author{C}
\affiliation{{affiliation3}
\affiliation{{affiliation4}
\affiliation{affiliation1}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please try to minimize your above code as much as possible. Most important thing: is `revtex4-1` needed in order to show the error? If not, please replace it with `article` or `report`. If yes, you have to provide a link to this document class.

Comment: Is this done for a journal contribution? If so, they will have certain conventions on the order of affiliations. They will most likely overrule your modification and set the affiliation of the first author to be first.

Comment: `authblk` is definitely incompatible with `revtex4-1`.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping
Just, in the current format, may i change the order? without using authblk

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to solve this problem.

An alternative ordering can be forced by including a list of `\affiliation` commands before the first `\author` in the desired order. Then use the exact same text for each affiliation when specifying them for each author.

```
\affiliation{affiliation3}
\affiliation{affiliation4}
\affiliation{affiliation1}

\author{A}
\affiliation{affiliation1}
\author{B}
\affiliation{affiliation2}
\author{C}
\affiliation{affiliation3}
\affiliation{affiliation4}
\affiliation{affiliation1}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing some curly brackets in your solution. Are you sure?